# Get last 3 rows in a SELECT statement and make it ASC order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this mysql query that i want to query only last 3 rows of my SELECT statement, and I want to reorder again my query to ASC order as the subquery is in DESC.

```
 SELECT * FROM( 
      SELECT * 
      FROM post_replies 
      WHERE post_replies.post_hash=:posthash 
      ORDER BY post_replies.reply_id DESC 
      LIMIT 3)
    ORDER BY reply_id ASC
```

This is the error that appears

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have
>   its own alias. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM( SELECT *
>   FROM post_replies WHERE post_replies.post_hash=:posthash ORDER BY
>   post_replies.reply_id DESC LIMIT 3) ORDER BY reply_id ASC

I don't understand on how i can put mysql Alias here as defined [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

how can i make my query get only the last 3 rows of my select statement and make the results in ASC order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is just telling you that you need to *call* your subselect something.  You put the alias after the right parenthesis after the subselect.  This should work:

```
 SELECT a.* FROM( 
      SELECT * 
      FROM post_replies 
      WHERE post_replies.post_hash=:posthash 
      ORDER BY post_replies.reply_id DESC 
      LIMIT 3) a
    ORDER BY a.reply_id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a MySQL expert, but the alias would go after the derived table, as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM( 
  SELECT * 
  FROM post_replies 
  WHERE post_replies.post_hash=:posthash 
  ORDER BY post_replies.reply_id DESC 
  LIMIT 3) ---> AS MyDerivedTable <---
ORDER BY reply_id ASC
```